# Concatenating two Pandas DataFrames while maintaining index order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate two DataFrames, with the resulting DataFrame preserving the index in order of the original two. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Houses':[10,20,30,40,50], 'Cities':[3,4,7,6,1]}, index = [1,2,4,6,8])


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Houses':[15,25,35,45,55], 'Cities':[1,8,11,14,4]}, index = [0,3,5,7,9])
```

Using `pd.concat([df, df2])` simply appends df2 to the end of df1. I am trying to instead concatenate them to produce correct index order (0 through 9).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `sort` for avoid warning and then [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2], sort=False).sort_index()

print(df)
   Cities  Houses
0       1      15
1       3      10
2       4      20
3       8      25
4       7      30
5      11      35
6       6      40
7      14      45
8       1      50
9       4      55
```

Comment: When trying this on a larger DataFrame, the rows were correctly ordered by index, but the column order changed. Any idea why?

Comment: @ConfusedDolphin - Because `sort=True`, try `sort=False`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
print(df.T.join(df2.T).T.sort_index())
```

Output:

```
   Cities  Houses
0       1      15
1       3      10
2       4      20
3       8      25
4       7      30
5      11      35
6       6      40
7      14      45
8       1      50
9       4      55
```

Comment: what pandas version use?

Comment: @jezrael 0.19.2

Comment: Really old, your code return warning in last version

Comment: @jezrael Edited mine